# Bsmnt Watch Dog Battery Flashing "Add Water" but the water level is to the line

Tags: sump-pump, battery

I have Basement Watch Dog Special.  The "Add Distilled Water" alarm keeps coming on.  The water level is to the line and the probe is submerged.  I measured the specific gravity of each cell: one is below average and one shows overcharged. the rest are at "optimal".

The battery hardly gets any use at all - I have lucked out, on no power outages.

Any suggestions, other than buying a new battery?

Thanks!

Comment: How old is the battery?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your plates are sulfated and the charger/watchdog is interpreting this as low water. In some cases a hard discharge cycle or two may extent the life, but it is probably time to replace. You don’t want to find out when you need it that the battery quickly dies when loaded down.